# Remove duplicate value and append the rest of the row value

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am using the below code to crawl through multiple links on a page and grab a list of data from each corresponding link:

carspider.py:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)

    item = CarscrapeItem()

    item['carType'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="listing__section  listing__section--key-details  listing__key-details  portable-one-whole  push--bottom"]//span[@itemprop="manufacturer"]//text()').get()
    item['model'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="listing__section  listing__section--key-details  listing__key-details  portable-one-whole  push--bottom"]//span[@itemprop="model"]//text()').get()
    item['variant'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="listing__section  listing__section--key-details  listing__key-details  portable-one-whole  push--bottom"]//span[@class="float--right"]//text()')[3].get()
    item['year'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="listing__section  listing__section--key-details  listing__key-details  portable-one-whole  push--bottom"]//span[@class="float--right"]//text()')[4].get()
    item['engineCapacity'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="listing__section  listing__section--key-details  listing__key-details  portable-one-whole  push--bottom"]//span[@class="float--right"]//text()')[5].get()
    item['transmission'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="listing__section  listing__section--key-details  listing__key-details  portable-one-whole  push--bottom"]//span[@class="float--right"]//text()')[6].get()
    item['seatCapacity'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="listing__section  listing__section--key-details  listing__key-details  portable-one-whole  push--bottom"]//span[@class="float--right"]//text()')[7].get()

    yield item
```

pipelines.py:

```
def __init__(self):
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    self.files = {}

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.file = open('%s_dataset.json' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.exporter = JsonLinesItemExporter(self.file)
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    file = self.files.pop(spider)
    file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    return item
```

I export the item to json file and the output is like this :

```
{"carType": "Honda", "model": "Civic", "variant": "TC VTEC Premium", "year": "2020", "engineCapacity": "1498 cc", "transmission": "Automatic", "seatCapacity": "5"}
{"carType": "Honda", "model": "Accord", "variant": "TC", "year": "2020", "engineCapacity": "1498 cc", "transmission": "Automatic", "seatCapacity": "5"}
```

I tried to make the output like this :

```
{"carType": "Honda", "model": "Civic", "variant": "TC VTEC Premium", "year": "2020", "engineCapacity": "1498 cc", "transmission": "Automatic", "seatCapacity": "5"
                     "model": "Accord", "variant": "TC", "year": "2020", "engineCapacity": "1498 cc", "transmission": "Automatic", "seatCapacity": "5"}
```

I want to remove the duplicate car type and append the rest of the row values to the existing car type. I suppose it will be better to make a recommender system in this way. Is it possible to do that with Scrapy? I searched responses related to duplicate values. Mostly, they are about Duplicates filter and the others did not work for me.

**EDIT :**

As my desired output is impossible to achieve. I tried out the suggestion given by Akshay Jain, which is almost similar to my desired output. And I finally get this output:

```
{
"BMW" : [
{ 
  "colour" : "White", 
  "engineCapacity" : "1998 cc", 
  "model" : "530e", 
  "seatCapacity" : "5", 
  "transmission" : "Automatic", 
  "variant" : "M Sport", 
  "warranty" : "5 years", 
  "year" : "2020"
}
], 
"Subaru" : [
{ 
  "colour" : "Silver", 
  "engineCapacity" : "1998 cc", 
  "model" : "WRX", 
  "seatCapacity" : "5", 
  "transmission" : "Automatic", 
  "variant" : "EyeSight", 
  "warranty" : "5 years", 
  "year" : "2020"
}, 
{ 
  "colour" : "Blue", 
  "engineCapacity" : "1995 cc",
  "model" : "XV", 
  "seatCapacity" : "5", 
  "transmission" : "Automatic",
  "variant" : "GT Edition", 
  "warranty" : "5 years", 
  "year" : "2019"
}, 
{ 
  "colour" : "Grey", 
  "engineCapacity" : "1995 cc", 
  "model" : "XV", 
  "seatCapacity" : "5", 
  "transmission" : "Automatic", 
  "variant" : "GT Edition", 
  "warranty" : "5 years", 
  "year" : "2019"
}, 
{ 
  "colour" : "Silver", 
  "engineCapacity" : "1995 cc", 
  "model" : "Forester", 
  "seatCapacity" : "5", 
  "transmission" : "Automatic", 
  "variant" : "S EyeSight", 
  "warranty" : "5 years", 
  "year" : "2019"
}
]
}
```

I add a python file with the following code to achieve this structure:

```
import json
with open("dataset.json", "r+") as json_data:
car = {}
item = json_data
for line in item:
    element = json.loads(line)
    brand = element.get("carType")
    if brand not in car:
        car[brand] = [element]
    else:
        car[brand].append(element)

json_data.seek(0) 
json.dump(car, json_data, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(", ", " : "))
json_data.truncate()
```

I refer to a few of the documentation and tutorial include https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp
http://www.compciv.org/guides/python/fundamentals/dictionaries-overview/

Hope it can help anyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For you just kind information, dictionaries key must be unique in python. So the output you are expecting that is not possible.
- Suggestion:
  You can store data in below way:

```
car = {
  "Honda": [
    {
      "model": "Civic",
      "variant": "TC VTEC Premium",
      "year": "2020",
      "engineCapacity": "1498cc",
      "transmission": "Automatic",
      "seatCapacity": "5"
    },
    {
      "model": "Accord",
      "variant": "TC",
      "year": "2020",
      "engineCapacity": "1498 cc",
      "transmission": "Automatic",
      "seatCapacity": "5"
    }
  ],
  "BMW": [
    {
      "model": "XYZ",
      "year": "2020",
      "transmission": "Automatic",
      "seatCapacity": "5"
    },
    {
      "model": "ABC",
      "year": "2020",
      "engineCapacity": "1498 cc",
      "transmission": "Automatic",
      "seatCapacity": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use below partial code to read you line by line data from file and you can write your own code to store the data in above format

```
import json
with open('PATH_TO_FILE/FILE_NAME.json') as f:
  data = f
  for line in f:
    line = json.loads(line)
    # YOUR CODE HERE
```

Comment: Where and how should I modify in order to achieve this structure? I'm new in python, any tutorial or documentation will be helpful. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can refer this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: After several hours working on this, I finally get this output! I'm kinda slow cause I face some problems in the dictionary. Btw thanks a lot! Really appreciate your help!